# Object iteration issue with PUG

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I'm making an external API call through a POST request and sending data to be rendered on a PUG file.

This is my route:

```
app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  request(`${url}${req.body.term}`, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(body);
      const listData = data.itemListElement;

      console.log(listData[0].result.image.contentUrl);

      res.render('results', {
        searchData: listData,
        searchTerm: req.body.term
      });
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

This is my current PUG file:

```
html
  head
    title= Results
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous")
    body
      table(class="table table-striped")
        thead(class="thead-dark")
          tr
            th(scope="col") Result for #{searchTerm}
            th(scope="col") Description
            th(scope="col") Image
        tbody
            each item in searchData
                tr
                    td(scope="row")= item.result.name
                    td(scope="row")= item.result.description
                    td(scope="row")= JSON.stringify(item.result.image)
```

I have been having issues trying to "grab" the image link so I can display it on the third column of my table.

When I console.log the key from the object, I'm able to retrieve it and I can see the link on my terminal. However, I get an error `Cannot read property 'contentUrl' of undefined` when I try to display the link on my PUG file.

The image link is found in the nested array of objects:

`listData[0].result.image.contentUrl`

Where `listData` is the array containing all the objects.

And when I add `console.log(listData[0].result.image.contentUrl)` in the route, I get the link shown in my terminal

In the code provided here I stringified the object to see what comes out and you can see the Url is right there:

[image]

I've tried almost everything, no clue what's the problem!

Comment: What happens when you replace that third td with `td(scope="row")= item.result.image.contentUrl` ?  Everything looks good in the code you posted, but could you edit your question and add the code that causes the "Cannot read property" error?

Comment: So, this is what happens when I just add what you wrote:

https://imgur.com/85325e5d-caa9-487f-b552-c38ad03b376d

Comment: Image not found when I click that link.

Comment: Hey @Graham, so I fuond the issue and it was something very stupid. Some objects, don't have the `image` property so the server crashed cause I assumed that every result had it. I just added a conditional and it works now. Thanks for the help nonetheless!

Comment: Glad to help any time.  You should now either (a) post an answer to your own question detailing the solution or (b) delete the question if you don't think there's significant value to others in the first option.  Thanks!